# java - Google Play Game Services

Tags: android, google-play-services

Google Play Game Services is testing:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseGameActivity {
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
    } 
}
```

When `onSignInFailed()` is called, the following pop-up message appears:

> the application is incorrectly configured. Check that the package name
>   and signing certificate match the client ID created in Developer
>   Console. Also, if the application is not yet published, check that the
>   account you are trying to sign in with is listed as a tester account.
>   See logs for more information

Comment: Did you ever end up solving this issue?

Comment: probably because you mix debug-keystore and release-keystore

Answer (score 14):

I have sovled the problem like this :)

1. Go to **Google Developper Console** https://cloud.google.com/console
2. Select Your game project, go to "APIs & Auth" > "Creditentials"
3. Delete all the "Client ID for Android application" you have

At this point, we don't have anything more to do in the Google Developper Console.

1. Go to **Android Developper Console** https://play.google.com/apps/publish
2. Select your game in Play service
3. Go to "linked applications"
4. Create a NEW linked application android and put it your production certificate SHA1
5. Create a NEW linked application android and put it your debug certificate SHA1
6. Wait a few to changes be deployed

Now, we need to clear the Android Application cache before trying to connect

1. Clear cache of your application
2. Launch your app

And... It's works !! (For me at least...) My problem was that I've created the linked apps from the *Google Developer Console* instead of the *Android Developper Console*...

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed (I had the same problem). The debug certificate bit is very important for testing, and in my case it did take a good 10 minutes or so for the updated links to go live, despite no indication of this in the console (it's a good idea to assume this kind of delay will always be present any time you make a similar update).

Comment: I've tried your answer but with no success. Do i have to create two different keystores, one for production and one for debug, and then link two application with the two certificates SHA1 from de two different keystores?

Comment: Working perfectly, all I had to do is to add the debug certificate sha1, got it from here: http://pongodev.com/get-sha1-for-debug/#comment-343